# Publishing a SQL Server Database project

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008

I've created a SQL Server database project that correctly deploys a database on my machine.  However, I need this project to create databases on QA's machine.  They do not know how to create a database from a script.

Is there a way a database project in Visual Studio 2010 can be published so all a non-technical user has to do is click an executable and the database will automatically install?

Comment: There is certainly a way. I'll pop back and answer later when I have time (if somebody else hasn't), but all the details for creating a database can be scripted into the project. The best way is probably to create a deployment project to run the script. This however will be problematic when you want to make changes as there's no way for VS to know what's changed. I think the best way for you is going to be to set up a dev environment where you can deploy the DB and they can access it.

Comment: I don't think that is what I need.  I basically need an executable that a user can use to create a database on their local machine.  The "Deploy" option on the Database project in Visual Studio does not give a way to deploy it if the user does not have Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is this MSDN article:  [Deploying a Database by Using the Database Publishing Wizard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb907585.aspx).